# PHP Subclasses in use

Tags: php

How would I use subclasses within a class? I tried using extends, but I don't think that is quite what I was looking for.

```
class Database
{
    protected $link;
    private $host, $database, $username, $password;

    public function __construct($host, $database, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        //GLOBAL $this->link

        if ($this->link->connect_errno)
            die('Connection Error: ' . $this->link->connect_errno);
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('host', 'database', 'username', 'password');
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }
}

class Users extends Database{
    public function getAll(){
        $stmt = Database->link->prepare('SELECT id, username, email FROM USERS');
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $email);
        while($stmt->fetch())
            $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'username' => $username, 'email' => $email);
        $stmt->close();
        return $row;
    }
}
```

Then in a file displaying contents...

```
$db = new Database(HOST, DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);
$users = $db->Users->getAll();
foreach($users as $user){
    echo $user['username'] . "<br />";
}
```

I think my issue is with `$stmt = Database->link->prepare` and `$users = $db->Users->getAll();`

I'm more of a C guy so the PHP method kinda got me. Can someone accurately describe what I need to do to obtain the correct way of doing subclasses?

Comment: This isn't very clear to me.  You mean actual inherited classes (in which case `extends` is what you want) or an inner class (class-within-a-class)?  Inner classes are not allowed to my knowledge.

Comment: Well can I do: Users::getAll(); ? I'm just trying to get all the users from a database, and the information is in the database class. Sorry if that's hard to understand what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think my issue is with `$stmt = Database->link->prepare` and `$users = $db->Users->getAll()`

You got that right.

As `Users` extends `Database`, it has access to the *protected* property `$link`, thus, you simply use it via `$this`, eg

```
$stmt = $this->link->prepare(...)
```

Now, you don't really want to be creating a new MySQL connection every time you instantiate a `Database` class or one of its descendants. Instead, you should pass the `mysqli` dependency into the constructor, eg

```
abstract class Database {
    protected $link;

    public function __construct(mysqli $link) {
        $this->link = $link;
    }
}

class Users extends Database {
    public function getAll() {
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare(...);
        // and so on
    }
}

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$usersDao = new Users($mysqli);
$users = $usersDao->getAll();
foreach($users as $user){
    echo $user['username'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for more indepth understanding. Perhaps this isn't what I want. I want classes such as Users, but I don't want to create a new class Database everytime Users or another class such as Categories is called. That's just calling for memory leaks.

Comment: @Jakes625 You aren't creating new `Database` classes every time. In fact, in my answer they are abstract and cannot be created directly at all. You would however need to create a `Users` or `Categories` class in order to use them.

Comment: Hmm, Maybe I could create a class variable inside of database and then use as $db->$users->getAll(); where $users is a var inside of Database with the new instance of the class Users.

Comment: @Jakes625 No, please don't do that. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle